# Is it possible to cross cast through a templated class via dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, class, casting, dynamic-cast

I'm dealing with an inheritance/casting problem and was wondering if anyone could help!
We used to have a class structure where class B inherits from class A as follows:

```
class A {
...
}

class B : public A {
...
}

class C : public B {
...
}
```

However, we're now implementing a new class structure where A and B inherit from base classes as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class ABase { 
// all of the current A's logic will be moved to here 
} 

template <typename T> 
class BBase : public ABase<T>{ 
// all of the current B's logic will be moved to here 
}
 
class A: ABase<AClass> {
// nothing here 
};
 
class B: BBase<BClass> {
// nothing here 
}

class C : public B {
...
}
```

The structure is illustrated in the linked picture.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgEHN.png)

I'm attempting to do a dynamic_cast from class C to class A but I'm getting a nullptr. It appears as if B cannot cast to BBase. Is it possible to cast from class B to class A? Is it possible to cast from class C to class A? Thanks!

nullptr example: [jdoodle.com/ia/fBE](http://jdoodle.com/ia/fBE)

Comment: `B` (and therefore `C `) does not derive from `A` - so such a cast will be ill-formed

Comment: Also note that a `Foo<T>` is its own distinct type and has no relation to a `Foo<U>`.  You can't cast between them.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the code that has the `dynamic_cast` that fails (a [mre]) and include the compiler details? A `dynamic_cast` shouldn't segfault (although it might throw an exception).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here's an example: [link](http://jdoodle.com/ia/fBE). Looks like the segfault is happening after because the dynamic cast fails and is returning a null pointer - may I ask why this is the case? Shouldn't I be able to cross cast?

Comment: You can't dynamic_cast between unrelated types. How is your new B related to new A? No inheritance happens between them. I think those types are also required to be polymorphic. Either way you have UB. There's nothing else to talk about it here. UB code can do anything, including segfault.

Comment: You should (almost) never call `dynamic_cast` (on a pointer) without checking if the returned pointer is not null before using it. If you would have done that, you would not have a segfault. It is hard to believe that someone try to make such complex class hierarchy without minimal understanding of how `dynamic_cast` works. Also hard to believe that you do code refactoring with a big change like this in a single pass.

Comment: sorry, the link above is just an example - I forgot to include the null check. But thanks for the help everyone!